# How can I add a comma to this list?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

In the code below, I need to put a comma at the end of the author names.

```
foreach($terms as $term){
echo  '<a href="'.esc_url(get_term_link( $term, 'product_author' )).'">'.esc_html($term->name).'</a>';
            }
```

**Example: A, B, C 

Note: 1. A comma is not required if the author is one.

2. There is no need for a comma after the last author's name.**

Answer (score 1):

In PHP this is usually achieved by imploding an array. Given an array like this:

```
$array = ['David', 'Charles', 'Peter', 'John'];
```

Doing this implode:

```
$result = implode(', ', $array);
```

Would give you this string:

```
David, Charles, Peter, John
```

See: [implode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php).

You can do the same with your links like this:

```
$links = [];
foreach ($terms as $term) {
     $links[]  = '<a href="' . 
                 esc_url(get_term_link($term, 'product_author')) .
                 '">' .
                 esc_html($term->name) .
                 '</a>';
}
echo implode(', ', $links);
```

Comment: Thanks... It works fine